# turtle module error with color()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program to have the user specify the colour of lines but I keep getting an error. Can someone please explain why this is happening

```
import turtle 
wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle
sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides: "))
angle = 360/ sides
length = int(input("Enter the length of sides: "))
line_color = input("Enter the color of the lines: ")
alex.color(line_color)

fill_color = input("Enter the fill color for the polygon:" )
alex.fillcolor(fill_color)
alex.begin_fill()
for i in range(sides):
        alex.forward(lenght)
        alex.left(angle)
alex.end_fill()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should run:

```
import turtle    

wn = turtle.Screen()    
alex = turtle.Turtle() # need parens    
sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides: "))    
angle = 360 / sides    
length = int(input("Enter the length of sides: "))    
line_color = input("Enter the color of the lines: ") # takes input like "red" or "black" etc.. 
alex.color(line_color)    
fill_color = input("Enter the fill color for the polygon:" )    
alex.fillcolor(fill_color)    
alex.begin_fill()    
for i in range(sides):    
        alex.forward(44)  # added 44, you had an undefined variable there which is not valid    
        alex.left(angle)    
alex.end_fill()
```

I added the value `44`, you will have to add whatever you require yourself or initialize the variable `length` to some value.

Comment: thank you mate I've thought there was a problem in the alex.color(line_color) line

Comment: You're welcome, the missing parens were the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there buddy. 
`alex.forward(length)`